# Edit JLabel text inside a method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I've created a `ScorePlayer` class which extends `JPanel` and added a `JLabel` score in the constructor.

Now I want to edit the Text of the Label in a method of the same class but I am not really sure how to do it. Do I have to create an Instance of the Object like `ScorePlayer scorePlayer = new ScorePlayer();` inside of the method?

EDIT
First of all, thanks for your help.
I've just created a local variable for the Label in my Constructor like:

```
ScorePlayer(String playerName) {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Var.scoreBoardWidth, 200));
    JLabel player = new JLabel();
    player.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 32));
    JLabel score = new JLabel(); 
    score.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 32)); 
    score.setText(Integer.toString(spielStand));
    add(player, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    add(score, gbc);
}
```

Now, I just made `JLabel score`global like:

```
JLabel score = new JLabel();
ScorePlayer() {
 //CODE
}
```

It was just a silly beginner's mistake.

Comment: No you do not want to do that as you'll be modifying the state of the **wrong** object/instance. You want to modify the state (the text on the JLabel) of the currently displayed ScorePlayer instance. This requires that you understand what an instance or object is, and how it differs from a variable.

Comment: I've lerned a lot about that topic the last weeks, however this problem brings me to my limits.

Comment: My suggestion: cancel this post -- you appear to be here a bit too early -- and try to see what you can do. Remember to try to change the state of the visualized GUI, not a new separate one, avoid using static variables for this purpose, study similar questions and see what you can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

From your question i understand that you will need to add a instance of a `JLabel` and after this your class will look like this

```
public class ScorePlayer {
      private JLabel labelOne;

 public ScorePlayer (JLabel label){
         this.labelOne = label;
   }//this is where you initialize a JLabel object
```

after you add those lines of code you have to add method `setLabel` like this

```
public void setLabel(String label){
    labelOne.setText(label);
 }// this is inside your ScorePlayer class
```

I hope this will help you.